# Google Sheets Скопировать комментарии на другой лист App Script

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Доброго времени суток уважаемые специалисты!
Помогите решить нетривиальную задачу - необходимо при помощи App Script в Google Sheets скопировать комментарии на другой лист одной книги но в те же ячейки. Комментарии оставляет как владелец книги так и другие пользователи.

Я уверен есть способ и пусть нетривиальный - но не могу найти.

Ссылка на саму таблицу - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W2y-9xFV5-VCzsW6CE0COaamnuSkOVN5bmaKbGUhs4Y/edit?usp=sharing

Спасибо всем за ответы заранее, буду с нетерпением ожидать!!!

`cell.getNotes()` или `cell.getNot()` получает только комментарии что оставил владелец, аналогично и `getComment()`

`Drive.Comments.list(document_id).items;` - данная функция получает абсолютно все комменты на листе - но нет ни функции ни свойства получить адрес ячейки этих комментов чтобы разместить в те же ячейки только на другом листе

Comment: Кто поделится мыслями - как получить из общего массива коммента адреса ячеек где числится коммент или может есть способ - конечно из всех перепробованных вариантов остается только создавать копию книгу - переносить данные toMove  все...

Comment: Насколько я знаю - пока что это невозможно. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756650

Comment: Хотя заданный вопрос имеет [давнюю историю](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839057/how-to-getcomments-from-google-sheets), вряд ли стоит рассчитывать на появление функциональности "писать комментарии где-либо" от чужого имени. Это нарушает права авторов комментариев. Даже при дублировании листа комментарии не будут перенесены на новую копию.